# Why is C# syntax highlighting not working sometimes?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Most of the time, when I write in code in Visual Studio, copy and paste it in the Stack Overflow answer box, the syntax color highlighting works. Sometimes, it doesn't.

Other times I spend over 15 minutes trying to fix it and then give up. One example of the one that didn't work is the answer I provided just [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37427296/3785314). Am I missing anything? If somebody finds the problem, can you share with me? I will be happy to go back to all my other answers with this problem and fix them all.

Comment: There is no C# tag on the question, so the highlighter doesn't know to use that language. Maybe you want to add it? Or you can always specify the language manually in your post.

Comment: @animuson Omg. I can't believe this. It worked. How can you specify the language manually? You can put this as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @Programmer <--language: lang-cs --> before the code snippet

Comment: @animuson This is weird because I just answered a new question and the  highlighting worked without the C# tag on the question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427571/how-to-set-scale-to-object-image-in-unity-3d-by-code/37427716#37427716

Comment: @Programmer Perhaps it's guessing it's java due to the android tag? The colouring  between C# and java should be almost identical.

Comment: In the meantime, they [made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983) the [syntax highlighter disappear and replaced it by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuCqeg4zV_o&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&t=51s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is dependent on the tags. Some tags have languages pre-defined, some tags let the highlighter interpret the language (default), and some tags do not enable highlighting features at all (none).

- **When there is only one tag with a specific language defined**, all of the code blocks will use that language.
- **When there are multiple tags with a specific language defined**, all code blocks will let the highlighter interpret the language on its own.
- **When any tag is set to default and no tags define a specific language**, all code blocks will let the highlighter interpret the language on its own.
- **When all tags are set to none**, no syntax highlights will occur.

You can view which language is set for a tag by [viewing the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) and looking for the "Code Language" line at the very bottom (below the Edit button).

These rules apply to the question *and* all its answers. You can override these rules by manually setting the language in your post, with either of these two methods:

1. Include a rule directly above the code block to override that code block only.
   Example: `<!-- language: lang-c -->`
2. Include a rule in your post that defines the language for all code blockes in that post.
   Example: `<!-- language-all: lang-c -->`

Comment: Have been here for over a year and didn't know this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Use [fenced code blocks](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks) (```` ``` ````) and define the [language for highlighting](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#syntax-highlighting) as "cs".

For example:

````
```cs
var x = 1
```
````

results in:

```cs
var x = 1
```

The highlight will differ from your IDE. If you want to check it indeed works, check the CSS style applied to the highlighted code section in your browser.

[Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971) a list of other ways to also achieve this.

And [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) a long, though not complete, list of supported languages (thanks goes to @PeterMortensen)

Comment: [The canonical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) (e.g., with all the supported language tags and their synonyms).

Comment: @PeterMortensen great! I find it incomplete and things might change, but I was looking for something like that! I've added it to the answer as it is really useful and better be more visible. Thanks!